# Can I link or have formulas between task times?

Tags: ms-project, tasks, task-management

Is it possible to use a formula to get information from "TASK A" as an input "work" in task B?

Example:

Task A is fixed duration of 2 weeks. I have assigned some resources and the total work they do is 60 hours. 
Now.. Task B is fixed work. The fixed work has to be 100 hours(predefined number) - [Work done in Task A] = 40 hours.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The Work field is not customizable. Furthermore, fields that are customizable with **formulas** such as Number1-30, Text1-30, etc. **can only use values from the task itself**, not other tasks.

If there are only a few such tasks that need to be updated, do it manually. However, if there are many you'll need **a macro to update one task based on another task.**  There are likely many ways to do this, what springs to mind is to tag these pairs of tasks with a code in a text field (such as Text1). The macro would loop through the tasks looking for a code that meets a pattern (e.g "Pair01_FixedWork") and then would search for its mate "Pair01_FixedDur" and update accordingly.

Note: the macro would need to be run whenever the driving task information changes.